# SQL aggregate quarterly records

Tags: sql

I'm trying to aggregate quarterly records that belong to unique customer ids.  I would then like to filter out those by $amount spent on X.
below is what I've coded:

```
select year, count(*), sum($spentX), customerid
from table A
where year = 2017
group by year, customerid
having sum($spentX)<=1000
```

Is this correct?  Also, how do I sum the results to give me 2017 total, this query lists all customerids so I have to aggregate in another software.

2nd question:
How do I use the above when I join two tables?

thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks correct. The way you have it set up your output would look something like the below. It is already filtered down to 2017 and grouped by the year and customer.

```
year   |    count(*)  |   sum($spentX)  |   customerid
2017   |    5         |   500.00        |   56
2017   |    8         |   800.00        |   43
2017   |    3         |   300.00        |   85
2017   |    2         |   200.00        |   56
2017   |    5         |   500.00        |   25
```

If you want to get a sum total for all customers who spent less than or equal to $1000 you would need put the entire thing in a subquery and sum it again

```
SELECT SUB.YEAR, SUM(SUB.TOTAL_COUNT), SUM(SUB.TOTAL_SPENT)
FROM (
      SELECT YEAR, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_COUNT, SUM($SPENTX) AS TOTAL_SPENT, CUSTOMERID
      FROM TABLE A
      WHERE YEAR = 2017
      GROUP BY YEAR, CUSTOMERID
      HAVING SUM($SPENTX)<=1000
      ) SUB
GROUP BY SUB.YEAR
```

OUTPUT:

```
YEAR   |    SUM(SUB.TOTAL_COUNT)  |   SUM(SUB.TOTAL_SPENT) 
2017   |    23                    |   2300.00
```

If you wanted to join that to another table say one with customer information it would look like this:

```
SELECT SUB.*  , C.CUSTOMER_NAME
FROM (
      SELECT YEAR, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_COUNT, SUM($SPENTX) AS TOTAL_SPENT, CUSTOMERID
      FROM TABLE A
      WHERE YEAR = 2017
      GROUP BY YEAR, CUSTOMERID
      HAVING SUM($SPENTX)<=1000
      ) SUB
INNER JOIN TABLE_CUSTOMERS C  ON C.CUSTOMERID = SUB.CUSTOMERID
```

The output for this query would look something like this:

```
YEAR   | TOTAL_COUNT  |   TOTAL_SPENT   |   customerid | CUSTOMER_NAME
2017   |    5         |   500.00        |   56         | LARRY
2017   |    8         |   800.00        |   43         | MARGE
2017   |    3         |   300.00        |   85         | JOHN
2017   |    2         |   200.00        |   56         | RICK
2017   |    5         |   500.00        |   25         | SAM
```

Comment: so joining the sub with another table to filter on another variable,  I put where c.newvariable=222 at the end but I get blank results

Comment: also, why would adding another variable like employee# to the sum total query give me a different 2017 total?  Shouldn't the sum(sub.Total_count) stay the same?

Comment: You would want to join on a field that the two tables have in common and then throw in the new variable constraint in your where statement. Would it be possible to show the columns of the table you are trying to join to? Is 222 the customer ID you want to narrow the query down to?

Comment: To answer your second question. Adding another field in the Select and the Group by should give you the same total if you add up the column but will give you a different value in each row because you are aggregating at a different level. If you add another variable in the Where statement you would end up with a different total because you are now removing rows from the equation entirely.

Comment: I want to be able to add two more columns to the above query but it still gives me different totals, I add the column name to the select and the group by as you said.  Each time I add a new column, I get a different total count.  I'll post this as another question since the comment box doesn't have space